# SQL Filter based on Case

Tags: sql, group-by, case

I have a table as such:

```
email | event

e1     a   
e1     c
e2     a
e3     b
e4     a
e4     b
e5     c
e6     d
```

I'm trying to create a query that gets only those who have event `a` exclusively

Desired output:

```
email  |  attended

e2       0
```

Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT
    tm.email,
    MAX(
    CASE
    WHEN tm.event = 'b' or tm.event = 'c' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END)
    as attended,
FROM
    table.events as tm
WHERE
    tm.event IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
    AND attended = 0
GROUP BY
    tm.email, attended
```

I can't seem to figure out the correct way to go about this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use aggregation:

```
select email
from events
group by email
having max(case when event = 'a' then 0 else 1 end) = 0
```

Or, if you want the entire record(s), you can filter with a `not exists` condition:

```
select e.*
from events e
where 
    e.event = 'a'
    and not exists (select 1 from events e1 where e1.email = e.email and e1.event <> 'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want emails that have only `'a'`, then I would use aggregation, but like this:

```
select email
from events
group by email
having min(event) = max(event) and min(event) = 'a';
```